# APT. Delete package "Dependencie", without deleting package "Needed"

Tags: apt

I want to delete nautilus, but I have a cool script named Folder Color, that has in his dependencies nautilus.

Can I mark in apt keep package folder-color and delete nautilus?

Comment: And what will you do with folder-color package?!? There is no any reason to keep it as long as it [change a color for a folder used only in Nautilus](https://launchpad.net/folder-color)...

Comment: it works with Nemo as well.

Comment: I think you are wrong: *[Just Ubuntu ;) It'll use Nautilus and the Humanity theme](http://foldercolor.tuxfamily.org/)*... But there is a workaround [here](http://ubuntuportal.com/2014/05/folder-color-make-your-folder-icon-in-nautilus-and-nemo-colorful.html) which will work only if you have Nautilus installed.

Comment: It works for Nemo. All that need's to be done is to change Nautilus for Nemo in script, that's all.

Comment: Yes, that's all as long as you have Nautilus installed :)

Comment: amm... No. I saw script and there is nothing that hardly set to work only with nautilus...

Answer (score 1):

[It seems](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/folder-color-easily-change-folder-icon.html) that Folder Color only works with nautilus. So, if you want to use Folder Color, you're stuck with nautilus. It may exist for other file managers (the site I linked to states it works with Nemo if you mess around with it a bit), so look into that.

Comment: it works with Nemo as well. And I'm using Nemo and Folder Color for some time.